# Minhag not to return home directly after shiva visit?

Tags: minhag, home-house, sitting-shiva

I was doing a shiva visit today and, when leaving, someone said we shouldn't walk home directly but instead should take a stroll before returning home. I had never heard of that *minhag* - but it might be *Sefaradi*.

Is this *minhag* known by others? Does it have sources in *halacha*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought is was after the levaya. I saw in Mourning in Halacha Chapter 10 S26:

> Some have the custom of leaving the funeral by a different route, if
>   possible from that which they came. See Ta’amei Haminhagim 834 - in
>   order to avoid meeting women who are taking part in the funeral.
>   Gesher Hachayim 14:20 writes in the same in the name of Zichron Shai.